# Is it possible to use the escape codes used in shell prompts elseware, such as with echo?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell-script, ascii

Example: When I run

`echo -e "\[\033[;33m\][\t \u (\#th) | \w]$\[\033[0m\]"`

The printed response is `\[\][    \u (\#th) | \w]$\[\]` (Where everything after the first `\[` and before the last `\]` is an orangey-brown.

However when I set the command prompt to `\[\033[;33m\][\t \u (\#th) | \w]$\[\033[0m\]` the command prompt is printed as `[21:55:17 {username} (89th) | {current directory path}]$` (Here the whole command prompt is the orangy-brown.)

In conclusion, my question is, can I have a command prompt design printed (with echo, cat, less, etc...) as if it were the command prompt?

Comment: Escape codes for colours work generally in ANSI terminals. The `\u`, `\w`, and similar are specific to PS1.

Comment: @choroba Alright, thanks for the info!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was [cross-posted to Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/660154/108618) and answered there. [Cross-posting is discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310).